# How to output a new form in redirected php files?

Tags: php

I am trying to pass variables buy echoing new forms after using header("Location: location.php"). So when it is redirected, it outputs the form in the redirectred php file.

```php
<?php

header("Location: location");
echo "<form><input type = 'submit' value ='try again' > </form>";
//expected output:the form outputs in the same files
?>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Redirect or not?

Comment: @Dharman   i am trying to redirect to the php file and open it on the redirected php file

Comment: The browser will never display the contents after `header("Location: location");`, because as soon as it sees this it will open the new page location and discard all the output from a previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `header("Location:page")` immediately exits your script and redirects the user to that page. However, I have successfully accomplished something very similar (to what I think you want) by scripting a Website Registration API.

In total, I wrote 3 critical scripts, plus the original form page, in/out functions, and an assortment of data storage modules to create a seamless process. Your needs might not be as complicated as mine, but I found this to be much more involved than a simple 'validation check'.

Basic outline:

1. page original form is on: submit sends form data to script
2. script parses incoming data and determines action

   - each input variable is parsed

     - if form data is empty: user is sent to original (blank) form page
     - if form data flags bad input: the form is reprinted (errors in red)
     - if form data is legit: data is stored; script advances to user portal
3. login/logoff functions

Try to solve your problem by thinking about each step of the process and breaking it down into bite-size pieces. (first you have to see the input, then you have to check the input, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

After the `header("Location:url");` no other command will be executed
but you can used  `document.getElementById("myForm").submit();`

```
<form id="form" action="/url"><input type = 'submit' value ='try again' > </form>";
//expected output:the form outputs in the same files
<script>
  document.getElementById("form").submit();

</script>
```

or used curl